# PyQt5: RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I have been trying to develop a multi-window application using the PyQt5 library. I wanted to have a second window dedicated for separate features. I was able to switch from the main window to the secondary window without any problems. However after attempting to switch back, I got the Recursion Error exception. Here is the relevant code:

```
import os
import sys
from functools import partial
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QPixmap
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QFrame, QMessageBox, QMenu         



class IpLogger(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(IpLogger, self).__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Main window")
        self.setFixedSize(648, 228)
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon("data\\icon\\WiFicon.ico"))
        self.loggerUI()



    def loggerUI(self):
        #Define font variable
        font = QtGui.QFont()

        #Button leading to second window
        self.mediaBtn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.mediaBtn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 180, 181, 41))
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.mediaBtn.setFont(font)
        self.mediaBtn.setObjectName("mediaBtn")
        self.mediaBtn.setText("Social Media")
        self.mediaBtn.clicked.connect(partial(self.showWindow, Media()))

    #Switching windows
    def showWindow(self, window):
        self.win = window
        self.win.show()
        self.close()



class Media(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Media, self).__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Second window")
        self.setFixedSize(300, 180)
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon("data\\icon\\WiFicon.ico"))
        self.mediaUI()

    def mediaUI(self):
        #Variables
        font = QtGui.QFont()

        #Button leading back to the main menu
        self.backBtn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.backBtn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(130, 123, 40, 40))
        font.setFamily("Segoe UI")
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.backBtn.setFont(font)
        self.backBtn.setObjectName("backBtn")
        self.backBtn.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(69, 69, 69, 0)")
        self.backBtn.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon("data\\icon\\back.png"))
        self.backBtn.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(40, 40))
        self.backBtn.clicked.connect(partial(self.showWindow, IpLogger()))

    #Switching windows
    def showWindow(self, window):
        self.win = window
        self.win.show()
        self.close()



def window():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = IpLogger()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

window()
```

Comment: Ok I will do that

Comment: Should be reproducible now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Explanation:

According to your code you create an IpLogger object, this IpLogger object creates in its loggerUI method that it is executed when a Media() object is built, that new object does the same in mediaUI(), that is, creates another IpLogger object, that is, you do what next:

```
IpLogger->loggerUI->Media->mediaUI->IpLogger->loggerUI->Media->...
```

#### Solution:

According to what is explained in the OP post, you only want to have a single IpLogger object and a single Media object, so both objects can be created in the window function and use the connections to exchange the visibility of one or the other depending on the case.

```py
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class IpLogger(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(IpLogger, self).__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Main window")
        self.setFixedSize(648, 228)
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon("data\\icon\\WiFicon.ico"))
        self.loggerUI()

    def loggerUI(self):
        # Define font variable
        font = QtGui.QFont()

        # Button leading to second window
        self.mediaBtn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.mediaBtn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 180, 181, 41))
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.mediaBtn.setFont(font)
        self.mediaBtn.setObjectName("mediaBtn")
        self.mediaBtn.setText("Social Media")


class Media(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Media, self).__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Second window")
        self.setFixedSize(300, 180)
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon("data\\icon\\WiFicon.ico"))
        self.mediaUI()

    def mediaUI(self):
        # Variables
        font = QtGui.QFont()

        # Button leading back to the main menu
        self.backBtn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.backBtn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(130, 123, 40, 40))
        font.setFamily("Segoe UI")
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.backBtn.setFont(font)
        self.backBtn.setObjectName("backBtn")
        self.backBtn.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(69, 69, 69, 0)")
        self.backBtn.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon("data\\icon\\back.png"))
        self.backBtn.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(40, 40))


def window():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    win = IpLogger()
    media = Media()

    win.mediaBtn.clicked.connect(media.show)
    win.mediaBtn.clicked.connect(win.close)

    media.backBtn.clicked.connect(win.show)
    media.backBtn.clicked.connect(media.close)

    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    window()
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It seems obvious now that you've pointed it out but it would've taken me ages to fix that without your help.